# How does Sansa know Ramsay's dogs are hungry?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In negotiation just before the war for Winterfall during *Game of Thrones* season 6, Ramsay said "I did not feed the dogs for seven days" but at that moment Sansa has already left from there. At the end of the war, Sansa reminded Ramsay of that.  How can it be?

I hope the explanation is not "Jon or others informed Sansa about what they talked about". I think there is a logical mistake at that scenes.

Comment: From my knowledge of GoT, all dogs are always hungry :)

Comment: Wht *wouldn't* Jon & Sansa dicsuss what Ramsay said. Some things are just too obvious to state.

Comment: I hate those sheep questions. 1 people ask it then everyone wonders why. It's a tv show, they had over 30 hours of footage to compress in an hour episode. They had her leave as if she just BURN ramsey with her response. Then she burn him again with his own word. They must have cut the useless dialog between Jon and her where he tells her how sick he is and how he didn't fed his dogs for 7 days. We already know he's sick so we didn't need that scene. Sorry I sound rude, but I've seen the circles of people running around saying hurr durrr plot holes. .. .. ... ........

Comment: Shouldn't that be Hodor plot holes...? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely **Jon or others informed Sansa about what they talked about.**

Not everything is shown on screen and it's reasonable to assume that Jon Snow may recap the conversation that he had with Sansa's *husband* when he sees Sansa next.  It's also possible that someone else in the party told Sansa that Ramsay said this when they were trying to decide if and how they should execute him.

To my knowledge there isn't a 'Word of God' answer to this question, the dialogue wasn't shown on screen, and this scene has not occurred in the books.  Until we hear more from the writers, see the discussion on screen (unlikely), or read this scene in the books (also unlikely) there isn't going to be another answer to this question.

Comment: How does Sansa get the dogs to get into the cell with Ramsey?  Obviously she didn't sneak down there on her own for secret, unauthorized revenge.  They cut off the conversation for the sake of drama after "Where is he?" but a lot of information could have been exchanged in the answering of that question.

"He's tied up in the dungeons."
"I want him.  He's mine.  I should feed his man-parts to the dogs."
"Well, he did say they were hungry....."

This is not to argue with anything you said, just seemed like the appropriate place to put the comment.

Comment: @AndrewMattson ramsay was in the kennels. That's the same place Reek lives, and where Fat Walda and baby were killed.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Still, it's not like they're going to share that with her and then expect her to do nothing, and the dogs were originally in separate cages, so the greater point still stands.  That doesn't happen without at least knowledge, let alone approval, from others.  This isn't a "Set Jamie Lannister free" type of scenario.

Comment: @AndrewMattson I agree with your overall point. Pretty sure this was a sanctioned execution. And unlike the Catelyn/Jaime situation, Sansa is really the political leader of the armies anyway so it's sanctioned because she carried it out.